# knockout.js not sorting observable array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I for the life of me can't get this array to sort appropriately.  I know the sort function works but the timing of some sort is off.  Can't seem to figure it out.

**UI**

```
 <!-- ko foreach: Times.sort(function (l, r) { app.utils.orderTime(l.Time(), r.Time()); }) -->
```

**Javascript**

```
function Day(date, updated) {

        var self = this;

        self.Times = ko.observableArray([]);

        var times = ko.utils.arrayMap(date.Times, function (item) {
            return new Time(item, updated);
        });

        self.Times.push.apply(self.Times, times);
    }
```

**Sort Function**

```
app.utils.orderTime = function(l, r) {  // l = "9:00 AM", r = "11:00 PM"
    var leftFormatted = new Date('1/1/2012 ' + l); // Sun Jan 01 2012 09:00:00 GMT-0700
    var rightFormatted = new Date('1/1/2012 ' + r); // Sun Jan 01 2012 23:00:00 GMT-0700

    return leftFormatted.compareTo(rightFormatted); // -1
};
```

**UPDATE:**

I went ahead and added a computed called TimeSorted and sorts great, but I cant push anything into the time array and have it updated unless I have `self.Times().sort(`... instead but then the order isnt kept.

```
        self.TimesSorted = ko.computed(function() {
            return self.Times.sort(function (l, r) { app.utils.orderTime(l.Time(), r.Time()); });
        });

 <!-- ko foreach: TimesSorted -->
```

Comment: As a general rule, I wouldn't mix my model into my view like that in the first place. Create a `ko.computed` property in your VM with the sorted list and bind to that instead.

Comment: Huh?  This array is on multiple objects, not the root view model???

Comment: Then that would make this even more wrong. You should be binding to your view model, not random other objects. You are abusing the MVVM pattern that knockout is designed for.

Comment: I am binding to my viewModel, this list is a part of my viewModel?  You are confusing me, this is an excel grid type layout with multiple nested arrays that have properties with different observables.  How about answer the problem, not diverge onto something else.

Answer (score 2):

The `sort` method modifies the array it acts on and thus changes the original array. The fact that it also returns that array is what confuses a lot of people. A binding like this shouldn't be modifying the array; it should be working with a copy of the array:

```
<!-- ko foreach: Times.slice(0).sort(...) -->
```

The observable array `sort` method changes the array (just like `push`, `splice`, etc.) and notifies subscribers of the change. It doesn't create a dependency on the array within a binding or computed observable. The `slice` method, on the other hand, does create a dependency.

If you really do want to sort the original array, this really shouldn't be done in a binding. I suggest you use an extender such as this:

```
ko.extenders.sorted = function (obs, sortFunction) {
    obs.sort(sortFunction);
    obs.subscribe(function (array) {
        array.sort(sortFunction);
    });
}

...

self.Times = ko.observableArray([]).extend({ sorted: function (l, r) { return app.utils.orderTime(l.Time(), r.Time()); } });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/f3SX2/

Comment: I noticed for my 15 items in the array it only calls the orderTime method 30 times.  Shouldnt it call it more then that?

Comment: I'm guessing it didn't work because you also needed to return something in your function. Sorry I didn't notice that too.

Comment: Awesome Ill use this and this post might be useful to someone now

Comment: But it wasnt the answer to this question about the sorting?

Answer (score -1):

Geez I feel a dumb.   I wasn't returning anything in the sort function of the array, just called a method.  This fixed it and I add to add `()` to the observable array.

```
<!-- ko foreach: Times().sort(function (l, r) { return app.utils.orderTime(l.Time(), r.Time()); }) -->
```

Comment: Don't do it this way. Here, you're getting the underlying array, and then sorting and returning it. You've now modified the array being held in your observable array, but without notifying any subscribers that it has been modified.

Comment: How should I do it then?  It's fine that the observable array was sorted like this.  It does notify my UI, it updates it.

Comment: You should use `Times.slice(0).sort`, as I described in my answer. If, on the other hand, you want to keep the original array sorted, you should do so in your view model. I'll add that to my answer as well.